# Snarkjs verification_key.zkey how to use it frontend to calculate more optimally?

Tags: zk, zk-snark, circom

currently while calculating proof with snarkjs it takes around 10-30 seconds to generate proof. out of which most of time is utilised to fetch these vkey file in directory which is around 120mb. so every time we want prove it fetching 120mb and then giving us proof any efficient way of handling these?

how to optimal save vkey file instead of fetching everytime